# How to disable IIS 8.5 ASP.NET 4.7.2 recycling on /bin changes and enable on /Views changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8.5, .net-4.7.2

I was read tons of articles where is specified that I can disable ASP.NET application recycling after file changes using `fcnMode="Disabled"`. I need applicaiton state (for example errors statistics).

Nice, but how to disable FCN on `/bin` but enable on `/Views` to update views.

The most strange is that IIS 8.5 after `fcnMode="Disabled"` blocks recycling in `/bin` and `/Views` but not updates views adter update *.cshtml from `/Views`.

IIS Express do the same apart updates views after update *.cshtml that is what I need.

I prepare such configuration for IIS.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" fcnMode="Disabled"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: in which config file you put this setting in root configuration or folder config?

Comment: I put this in root because I want disable FCN on /bin. Can I put in other place to disable /bin FCN?

Comment: create a web.config file for a folder for which you want to disable fcn mode.like[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5yWJ.png)